# Speech to text on windows server 2008 with c# and supports multilanguage?

Tags: c#, windows-server-2008, speech-recognition

I'm looking for speech (wave files) to text on windows server 2008 (or win server 2008 r2) using c# (at least an api that i can call from c#) that supports multilanguage.

As far as i know i can't use .net speech (sapi) because it works only on vista \ windows 7.

I can't use Microsoft Speech Platform because it not supports all the languages i need (as far as i checked there is no Hebrew (he) support).

It can't be a web based service (i need it on my server).

I'm looking for something that can be used in commercial software and i'm also willing to pay for a third party product.

Can you please help me with that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have text-to-speech listed as a tag but the description sounds like speech recognition. If I understand what you want to do it is to take a wav file with speech in it and convert it too text.  Actually this is not even normal speech recognition because most of the speech reco systems work on targeted speech input that use grammars to restrict the search space that the speech engine has to use.  I think what you are describing is automatic translation or transcription, akin to what Google Voice does to your voice mail messages when it sends you a text translation in an email.  This is a much more difficult problem and the state-of-the-art is not that advanced right now.  Most of these solutions are offered as services and the best ones still use human translators when the speech recognition confidence rate is low.  I think the leader in this area is Nuance. I would check with them for a solution.  I know they recently bought out a company that provides this automated transcription service and perhaps they now offer it as a product.  They are also a leader in transcribing doctors orders/findings automatically to text with their product Dragon Naturally Speaking.

Comment: Thanks for the link to nuance, i sent them an email. i fixed the tag to speech-recognition. i'm not looking for translation, if the conversation in English i want to text to be in English. if it in Hebrew i want the text to be in Hebrew. do you know more companies that has this kind of solutions?

Comment: You are looking for transcription then. None if these systems will be able to detect the language. You will either need a profile for users indicating their language preference or prompt them for the language they want to use and then switch the  ASR engine for that language.  Most of these types of systems seem to focus in the medical market.  Another provider is InfraWare (http://www.infraware.com/speech_recognition.php). Unfortunately it looks like Nuance has bought out most of the players in this market.

Comment: Hi Kevin, yes a transcription is exactly what i need. Thank you very much you really helped me!